# Vertical Text Orientation in QML

Tags: qt, qml

How can i display a text in QML with vertical orientation like below

[image]

```
Text {
    id: name13
    text: qsTr("John")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, need to use `rotation` property and use the angle, in my case it is `270`

```
Text {
    id: name13
    text: qsTr("John")
    rotation : 270
}
```